# Convert list of list with column name in each list to a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists as given below. How to convert that to a dataframe?

```
        a = [["id = abc12", "value1=2.3", "value2=3.4"],["id = abcd4", "value1=4.6", "value2=3.45"],
         ["id = abr42", "value1=6.2", "value2=6.1"], ["id = abyt5",  "value2=1.06"],
         ["id = abndf1", "value1=3.21", "value2=8.65"],["id = abuz2", "value1=0.9", "value2=6.89"]]


    pd.DataFrame(a)
```

[image]

But the output is not aligned properly for row 3. I am expecting 3 columns [id, valu1, value2] and there corresponding values, if the value is not present then that columns should have null or na

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your data into one of the formats `pandas` can understand. It can be for example:

- list of lists with rows
- dict `column_name->whole column contents in a list`
- list of dicts, where list element represents a row and dict is `column_name->column contents for this row`

The later which seems like the most straightforward approach in your case.
I am going to split each string inside the lists into tuples and convert each inside list into dict.

I also convert numbers to float (instead of string) automatically. If the values in `value1` and `value2` are supposed to be strings - delete the function `try_cast` and its application.

```
import pandas as pd

def try_cast(value, cast_type=float):
    try:
        return cast_type(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

def get_tuple(row_entity):
    parsed_row_entity = list(map(lambda x: try_cast(x.strip()), row_entity.split("=")))
    assert len(parsed_row_entity) == 2
    
    return tuple(parsed_row_entity)
    
df = pd.DataFrame([dict([get_tuple(entity) for entity in row]) for row in a])
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
id         object
value1    float64
value2    float64
dtype: object
       id  value1  value2
0   abc12    2.30    3.40
1   abcd4    4.60    3.45
2   abr42    6.20    6.10
3   abyt5     NaN    1.06
4  abndf1    3.21    8.65
5   abuz2    0.90    6.89
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(
    df.stack()
    .str.split('=')
    .explode()
    .str.strip()
    .groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(tuple)
    .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: dict(list(x)))
    .tolist()))
```

Output:

```
       id value1 value2
0   abc12    2.3    3.4
1   abcd4    4.6   3.45
2   abr42    6.2    6.1
3   abyt5    NaN   1.06
4  abndf1   3.21   8.65
5   abuz2    0.9   6.89
```